# Braintree payment gateway `confirm_payment_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nameerror, braintree

i'm running into an error while trying to incorporate the braintree gem into my rails 3 app. what's really strange is that i was able to successfully install it in one app on my system then when i try to run it on another app is get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `confirm_payment_url' for #<#<Class:0x103a2bf08>:0x103a2a298>
```

here is the default code that i'm using:

```
<h1>Payment: $<%= h @amount %></h1>

<% if @result -%>
  <div style="color: red;"><%= h @result.errors.size %> error(s)</div>
<% end -%>

<%= form_for :transaction,
     :params => @result && @result.params[:transaction],
     :errors => @result && @result.errors.for(:transaction),
     :builder => ApplicationHelper::BraintreeFormBuilder,
     :url => Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url,
     :html => {:autocomplete => "off"} do |f| -%>
  <%= field_set_tag "Customer" do -%>
    <%= f.fields_for :customer do |c| -%>
  <div><%= c.label :first_name, "First Name" %></div>
  <div><%= c.text_field :first_name %></div>
  <div><%= c.label :last_name, "Last Name" %></div>
  <div><%= c.text_field :last_name %></div>
  <div><%= c.label :email, "Email" %></div>
  <div><%= c.text_field :email %></div>
 <% end -%>
 <% end -%>
 <%= field_set_tag "Credit Card" do -%>
 <%= f.fields_for :credit_card do |c| -%>
  <div><%= c.label :number, "Number" %></div>
  <div><%= c.text_field :number %></div>
  <div><%= c.label :expiration_date, "Expiration Date (MM/YY)" %></div>
  <div><%= c.text_field :expiration_date %></div>
  <div><%= c.label :cvv, "CVV" %></div>
  <div><%= c.text_field :cvv %></div>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<%= hidden_field_tag :tr_data, Braintree::TransparentRedirect.transaction_data(
   :redirect_url => confirm_payment_url,         
   :transaction => {:type => "sale", :amount => @amount}
    ) %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end -%>
```

and here is the payments controller

```
  def confirm

@result = Braintree::TransparentRedirect.confirm(request.query_string)
if @result.success?
  render :action => "confirm"
else
  @amount = calculate_amount
  render :action => "new"
end
end
```

what type of changes could have this result where one rails app will recognize this method but another won't? really scratching my head on this one. thanks for your help.

Comment: What is different between the two applications? Are they the same versions of Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never define `confirm_payment_url` you most likely have an error in your applications routes however it is dificult to day without more information.

In the documentation provided by Braintree for the transparent redirect it seems as if this is a url that you want to send the customer back to after the payment is processed and that `confirm_payment_url` is not provided Braintree. You can see the documentation I am referencing [here](http://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/transactions/create_tr).

Comment: yes - my routes were missing:

match 'payments/confirm' => 'payments#confirm', :as => :confirm_payment

which was weird because i still had 

match 'payments/new', :to => 'payments#new', :as => :new_payment 

thanks for your help!

Comment: Anytime, glad I was able to help.